# How do I create a table in the back of my other tables?

Tags: html, css

I'm new in coding HTML and CSS, I designed an email template in XD and code 95% of it but I can't figure out how to code the header and bring it to the back and overlay part of it with another white table.

Another question, how can I make the button smaller like the preview?

Here's the preview of the header of my design : https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4HQv.jpg
Here's what I code so far :

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
 <title>Financing Senior Housing Since 1992 | LTC Properties Inc.</title>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

 <style type="text/css">
  /* Google font import Lato */
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');

  /* Outlook link fix */
  #outlook a {
   padding: 0;
  }

  /* Hotmail background & line height fixes */
  .ExternalClass {
   width: 100% !important;
  }

  .ExternalClass,
  .ExternalClass p,
  .ExternalClass span,
  .ExternalClass font,

  /* Image borders & formatting */
  img {
   outline: none;
   text-decoration: none;
   -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  }

  a img {
   border: none;
  }

  /* Re-style iPhone automatic links (eg. phone numbers) */
  .appleLinksGrey a {
   color: #575F65 !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;

  }

  /* Hotmail symbol fix for mobile devices */
  .ExternalClass img[class^=Emoji] {
   width: 10px !important;
   height: 10px !important;
   display: inline !important;
  }
  
  /* Button hover colour change */
  .CTA:hover {
   background-color: #0162B2 !important;
  }


  @media screen and (max-width:640px) {
   .mobilefullwidth {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
   }

   .logo {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
   }

   .h1 {
    font-size: 24px !important;
    line-height: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-top: 20px !important;
   }

   .h2 {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    line-height: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
   }

   .p {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    line-height: 20px !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
   }

   .p-b {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    line-height: 20px !important;
    padding-left: 20px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
   }

   .CTA_wrap {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
   }

   .CTA_wrap2 {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    padding-bottom: 25px !important;
   }

   
   .unsubscribe {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
   }

   .us-img {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
   }
   .footer {
    font-size: 11px !important;
    line-height: 16px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
   }

    
  }

 </style>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>


<body style="padding:0; margin:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; background-color:#EEEEEE; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#575F65">
     

<!-- // FULL EMAIL -->
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>

  <!-- // LEFT SPACER CELL *** MUST HAVE A BACKGROUND COLOUR -->
  <td bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="font-size:0px">&zwnj;</td>
  <!-- LEFT SPACER CELL // -->

   <!-- // MAIN CONTENT CELL -->
   <td align="center" width="600" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     
     <tbody>

      <!-- LOGO -->
      <tr>
       <td class="logo" align="center" bgcolor="#223663" style="padding-top: 30px;padding-bottom: 29px;">
        <a href="https://www.123.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8060fh3df/123.png?raw=1" width="98" height="60" alt="TP logo"> </a>

       </td>
      </tr>

      <!-- HERO CONTENT -->
      <tr>
       <td class="h1" align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style=" padding-left: 60px; padding-right: 60px; padding-top: 30px;padding-bottom: 0px; font-size:26px; line-height: 30px; font-weight: 700; color: #444A4E;">
         Need Financing? We’ve got it.
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="p" align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style=" padding-left: 60px; padding-right: 60px; padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom: 15px; font-size:14px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #575F65;">
         Challenging times demand adaptive measures. While many capital providers are slowing or completely halting investments, LTC remains open for business. We're constantly thinking outside of the REIT box to provide creative financing solutions.<br/><br/>Of course, we continue to offer our core NNN and JV structures. </span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">But, did you know we also offer a variety of structured finance products?</span><span> These solutions provide a range of levers LTC can pull to help finance projects.
      </tr>

      <!-- CALL TO ACTION -->
      <tr>
             <td class="CTA_wrap" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left" style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 60px; padding-left: 60px;">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">

         <!-- // BUTTON -->
         <tr>
          <td class="CTA" align="left" style="position: left; border-radius: 0px; padding-top: 15px; padding-right: 25px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 25px;" bgcolor="#0071CE"><a href="https://www.ltcreit.com/contact-us/" target="_blank" style=" color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 700; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 0px;  display: inline-block;">Contact Us!</a>
          </td>
         
                  </tr>

      <!-- LINE -->
      <tr>
       <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top: 30px;padding-bottom: 25px;">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4va5ixmmu3ako5/line-e.png?raw=1" width="480" height="1">

       </td>

      <!-- BENEFITS OF STRUCTURED FINANCE -->
      <tr>
       <table>
         <tbody>
          <tr>             
           <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 0px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; font-weight: 700; text-align: left; color: #444A4E;">
           <img align="left" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3jmuxhagx0b509/title_shape_e.png?raw=1" width="18" height="31">  &zwnj;BENEFITS OF STRUCTURED FINANCE:
           </td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        <table>
       <tr>
       <td class="p-b" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style=" padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 5px; font-size:14px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #575F65;">
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Provide liquidity through releasing “trapped” equity in properties<br>
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Bridge maturing loans while waiting for the market to return<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;to normal<br>
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Fund construction for shovel-ready projects<br>
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Fund existing projects where other investors have backed away<br>
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Provide an exit plan for equity investors who may have their own<br>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;liquidity needs<br></span>
      </tr>

      <!-- LINE -->
      <tr>
       <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top: 25px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4va5ixmmu3ako5/line-e.png?raw=1" width="480" height="1">

       </td>

      <!-- PODUCTS INCLUDE -->
      <tr>  
      <table>
         <tbody>           
           <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 0px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; font-weight: 700; text-align: left; color: #444A4E;">
           <img align="left" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3jmuxhagx0b509/title_shape_e.png?raw=1" width="18" height="31">  &zwnj;PRODUCTS INCLUDE:
           </td>
     </tbody>

    </tr>
        
        <tr>
       <td class="p-b" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style=" padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 5px; font-size:14px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #575F65;">
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Mezzanine&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Preferred Equity<br>
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Bridge&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Construction Financing<br>
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Unitranche Financing<br>
      </tr>

      <!-- LINE -->
      <tr>
       <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4va5ixmmu3ako5/line-e.png?raw=1" width="480" height="1">

       </td>

      <!-- DEAL PARAMETERS -->
      <tr>  
      <table>
         <tbody>           
           <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 0px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; font-weight: 700; text-align: left; color: #444A4E;">
           <img align="left" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3jmuxhagx0b509/title_shape_e.png?raw=1" width="18" height="31">  &zwnj;DEAL PARAMETERS:
           </td>
       </tbody>

      </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="p-b" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style=" padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 5px; font-size:14px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #575F65;">
         </span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">Transaction Size:</span><span><br>$1 million - $100 million<br><br>
         </span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">Property Types:</span><span><br>Independent Living, Assisted Living, Memory Care, Skilled Nursing<br><br>
         </span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">Locations:</span><span><br>Contiguous USA<br><br>
         </span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">Financing Types:</span><span><br>NNN, JV, Mezzanine, Bridge, Construction, Unitranche, Preferred Equity<br><br>
         </span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">Operators:</span><span><br>Regional, growth-oriented<br>   
      </tr>

      <!-- LINE -->
      <tr>
       <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4va5ixmmu3ako5/line-e.png?raw=1" width="480" height="1">

       </td>

       <!-- ABOUT LTC -->
      <tr>  
      <table>
         <tbody>           
           <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 0px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; font-weight: 700; text-align: left; color: #444A4E;">
           <img align="left" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3jmuxhagx0b509/title_shape_e.png?raw=1" width="18" height="31">  &zwnj;ABOUT LTC:
           </td>
       </tbody>

      </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="p-b" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="align-items: center; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 5px; font-size:14px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #575F65;">
         </span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">180+ Investments | 27 States | 30 Operating Partners</span><span>   
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class=us-imga lign="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <a href="https://www.om/file.cfm/1/docs/map_home_033120.jpg" target="_blank"> <img src="https://wwcom/file.cfm/1/docs/map_home_033120.jpg" width="460" height="285"> </a>

       </td>
       <tr>
       <td class="p-b" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style=" padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 5px; font-size:14px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #575F65;">
         Shared success is based on partnership and alignment. Our business is 
         about much more than real estate. It is about the operators who run 
         the communities and the residents who call our buildings home.<br>
         <br>
         We focus on building strong, long-term relationships and work to align 
         interests ensuring that all businesses are supported to create the best 
         outcomes for all.
           
      </tr>
      
      <!-- CALL TO ACTION -->
      <tr>
       <td class="CTA_wrap2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom: 25px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">

         <!-- // BUTTON 2 -->
         <tr>
          <td class="CTA" align="center" style="position: center; border-radius: 0px; padding-top: 15px; padding-right: 25px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 25px;" bgcolor="#0071CE"><a href="https://www.ltcreit.com/contact-us/" target="_blank" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 21px; font-weight: 700; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 0px;  display: inline-block;">Contact Us Today</a>
          </td>
         </tr>

       
     </tbody>
    </table>

   </td>

   
  <!-- // RIGHT SPACER CELL *** MUST HAVE A BACKGROUND COLOUR -->
  <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:0px">&zwnj;</td>
  <!-- RIGHT SPACER CELL // -->

 </tr>

</table>
<tr>
 <!-- // SOCIAL MEDIA -->

     <td class="footer" align="center" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style=" padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 20px; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 400; text-align: center; color: #575F65;">

     <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/0k25a3lkki3pbip/linkedin_e.png?raw=1" width="19" height="18" style="padding-right: 8px" "padding-bottom: 10px"><a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lnq77di7mue1zs/twitter_e.png?raw=1" width="22" height="18" style="padding-right: 8px"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/as39vdrbwtpvvp7/facebook_e.png?raw=1" width="18" height="18" style="padding-right: 7px"></a><a style=" padding-bottom: 20px" href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5clso0ov6qw97g/instagram_e.png?raw=1" width="18" height="18" style="padding-right: 7px"></a><br>

<!-- // FOOTER -->
        © 2020 , Inc<br>
<a class="appleLinksGrey" style="color: #575F65; " href="https://www..com">www.website.com</a>   |   1-8655<br>
e, CA 91361<br>
       </td>
      </tr>

<!-- FULL EMAIL // -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Stackerexp, that was really helpful. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to overlay different table rows over each other (someone correct me if i'm wrong) so I instead moved your top header containing the logo into a seperate div outside of the table and applied a negative margin to the table itself:

```
<div class="logo" align="center" style="background-color:#223663; padding-top: 
30px;padding-bottom: 29px; height:125px;">
                            <a href="https://www.123.com" target="_blank"><img 
src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8060fh3df/123.png?raw=1" width="98" height="200" alt="TP 
logo"> </a>
```

and

```
<table width="100%" style="margin-top:-50px" border="0" cellspacing="0" 
cellpadding="0">
```

To make the button as small as the text and not the entire width you can set 'display: inline' to the element containing it:

```
<tr style="display:inline">
```

I wouldn't advise making this entire page as a table but if you have no choice but to stick to it, here is the full code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
 <title>Financing Senior Housing Since 1992 | LTC Properties Inc.</title>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

 <style type="text/css">
  /* Google font import Lato */
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');

  /* Outlook link fix */
  #outlook a {
   padding: 0;
  }

  /* Hotmail background & line height fixes */
  .ExternalClass {
   width: 100% !important;
  }

  .ExternalClass,
  .ExternalClass p,
  .ExternalClass span,
  .ExternalClass font,

  /* Image borders & formatting */
  img {
   outline: none;
   text-decoration: none;
   -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  }

  a img {
   border: none;
  }

  /* Re-style iPhone automatic links (eg. phone numbers) */
  .appleLinksGrey a {
   color: #575F65 !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;

  }

  /* Hotmail symbol fix for mobile devices */
  .ExternalClass img[class^=Emoji] {
   width: 10px !important;
   height: 10px !important;
   display: inline !important;
  }
  
  /* Button hover colour change */
  .CTA:hover {
   background-color: #0162B2 !important;
  }


  @media screen and (max-width:640px) {
   .mobilefullwidth {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
   }

   .logo {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
   }

   .h1 {
    font-size: 24px !important;
    line-height: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-top: 20px !important;
   }

   .h2 {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    line-height: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
   }

   .p {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    line-height: 20px !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
   }

   .p-b {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    line-height: 20px !important;
    padding-left: 20px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
   }

   .CTA_wrap {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
   }

   .CTA_wrap2 {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    padding-bottom: 25px !important;
   }

   
   .unsubscribe {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
   }

   .us-img {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
   }
   .footer {
    font-size: 11px !important;
    line-height: 16px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
   }

    
  }

 </style>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>


<body style="padding:0; margin:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; background-color:#EEEEEE; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#575F65">
     
<div class="logo" align="center" style="background-color:#223663; padding-top: 30px;padding-bottom: 29px; height:125px;">
        <a href="https://www.123.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8060fh3df/123.png?raw=1" width="98" height="200" alt="TP logo"> </a>

       </div>
<!-- // FULL EMAIL -->
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>

  <!-- // LEFT SPACER CELL *** MUST HAVE A BACKGROUND COLOUR -->
  <td bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="font-size:0px">&zwnj;</td>
  <!-- LEFT SPACER CELL // -->

   <!-- // MAIN CONTENT CELL -->
   <td align="center" width="600" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

    <table width="100%" style="margin-top:-50px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     
     <tbody>

      <!-- LOGO -->
      <tr>
       
      </tr>

      <!-- HERO CONTENT -->
      <tr>
       <td class="h1" align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style=" padding-left: 60px; padding-right: 60px; padding-top: 30px;padding-bottom: 0px; font-size:26px; line-height: 30px; font-weight: 700; color: #444A4E;">
         Need Financing? We’ve got it.
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="p" align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style=" padding-left: 60px; padding-right: 60px; padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom: 15px; font-size:14px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #575F65;">
         Challenging times demand adaptive measures. While many capital providers are slowing or completely halting investments, LTC remains open for business. We're constantly thinking outside of the REIT box to provide creative financing solutions.<br/><br/>Of course, we continue to offer our core NNN and JV structures. </span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">But, did you know we also offer a variety of structured finance products?</span><span> These solutions provide a range of levers LTC can pull to help finance projects.
      </tr>

      <!-- CALL TO ACTION -->
      <tr>
             <td class="CTA_wrap" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left" style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 60px; padding-left: 60px;">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">

         <!-- // BUTTON -->
         <tr style="display:inline">
          <td class="CTA" align="left" style="position: left; border-radius: 0px; padding-top: 15px; padding-right: 25px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 25px;" bgcolor="#0071CE"><a href="https://www.ltcreit.com/contact-us/" target="_blank" style=" color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 700; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 0px;  display: inline-block;">Contact Us!</a>
          </td>
         
                  </tr>

      <!-- LINE -->
      <tr>
       <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top: 30px;padding-bottom: 25px;">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4va5ixmmu3ako5/line-e.png?raw=1" width="480" height="1">

       </td>

      <!-- BENEFITS OF STRUCTURED FINANCE -->
      <tr>
       <table>
         <tbody>
          <tr>             
           <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 0px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; font-weight: 700; text-align: left; color: #444A4E;">
           <img align="left" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3jmuxhagx0b509/title_shape_e.png?raw=1" width="18" height="31">  &zwnj;BENEFITS OF STRUCTURED FINANCE:
           </td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        <table>
       <tr>
       <td class="p-b" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style=" padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 5px; font-size:14px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #575F65;">
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Provide liquidity through releasing “trapped” equity in properties<br>
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Bridge maturing loans while waiting for the market to return<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;to normal<br>
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Fund construction for shovel-ready projects<br>
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Fund existing projects where other investors have backed away<br>
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Provide an exit plan for equity investors who may have their own<br>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;liquidity needs<br></span>
      </tr>

      <!-- LINE -->
      <tr>
       <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top: 25px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4va5ixmmu3ako5/line-e.png?raw=1" width="480" height="1">

       </td>

      <!-- PODUCTS INCLUDE -->
      <tr>  
      <table>
         <tbody>           
           <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 0px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; font-weight: 700; text-align: left; color: #444A4E;">
           <img align="left" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3jmuxhagx0b509/title_shape_e.png?raw=1" width="18" height="31">  &zwnj;PRODUCTS INCLUDE:
           </td>
     </tbody>

    </tr>
        
        <tr>
       <td class="p-b" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style=" padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 5px; font-size:14px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #575F65;">
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Mezzanine&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Preferred Equity<br>
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Bridge&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Construction Financing<br>
         <span style="font-size: 11px;">◆</span> Unitranche Financing<br>
      </tr>

      <!-- LINE -->
      <tr>
       <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4va5ixmmu3ako5/line-e.png?raw=1" width="480" height="1">

       </td>

      <!-- DEAL PARAMETERS -->
      <tr>  
      <table>
         <tbody>           
           <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 0px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; font-weight: 700; text-align: left; color: #444A4E;">
           <img align="left" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3jmuxhagx0b509/title_shape_e.png?raw=1" width="18" height="31">  &zwnj;DEAL PARAMETERS:
           </td>
       </tbody>

      </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="p-b" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style=" padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 5px; font-size:14px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #575F65;">
         </span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">Transaction Size:</span><span><br>$1 million - $100 million<br><br>
         </span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">Property Types:</span><span><br>Independent Living, Assisted Living, Memory Care, Skilled Nursing<br><br>
         </span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">Locations:</span><span><br>Contiguous USA<br><br>
         </span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">Financing Types:</span><span><br>NNN, JV, Mezzanine, Bridge, Construction, Unitranche, Preferred Equity<br><br>
         </span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">Operators:</span><span><br>Regional, growth-oriented<br>   
      </tr>

      <!-- LINE -->
      <tr>
       <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4va5ixmmu3ako5/line-e.png?raw=1" width="480" height="1">

       </td>

       <!-- ABOUT LTC -->
      <tr>  
      <table>
         <tbody>           
           <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 0px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 30px; font-weight: 700; text-align: left; color: #444A4E;">
           <img align="left" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3jmuxhagx0b509/title_shape_e.png?raw=1" width="18" height="31">  &zwnj;ABOUT LTC:
           </td>
       </tbody>

      </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="p-b" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="align-items: center; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 5px; font-size:14px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #575F65;">
         </span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">180+ Investments | 27 States | 30 Operating Partners</span><span>   
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class=us-imga lign="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <a href="https://www.om/file.cfm/1/docs/map_home_033120.jpg" target="_blank"> <img src="https://wwcom/file.cfm/1/docs/map_home_033120.jpg" width="460" height="285"> </a>

       </td>
       <tr>
       <td class="p-b" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style=" padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 5px; font-size:14px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #575F65;">
         Shared success is based on partnership and alignment. Our business is 
         about much more than real estate. It is about the operators who run 
         the communities and the residents who call our buildings home.<br>
         <br>
         We focus on building strong, long-term relationships and work to align 
         interests ensuring that all businesses are supported to create the best 
         outcomes for all.
           
      </tr>
      
      <!-- CALL TO ACTION -->
      <tr>
       <td class="CTA_wrap2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom: 25px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">

         <!-- // BUTTON 2 -->
         <tr>
          <td class="CTA" align="center" style="position: center; border-radius: 0px; padding-top: 15px; padding-right: 25px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 25px;" bgcolor="#0071CE"><a href="https://www.ltcreit.com/contact-us/" target="_blank" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 21px; font-weight: 700; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 0px;  display: inline-block;">Contact Us Today</a>
          </td>
         </tr>

       
     </tbody>
    </table>

   </td>

   
  <!-- // RIGHT SPACER CELL *** MUST HAVE A BACKGROUND COLOUR -->
  <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-size:0px">&zwnj;</td>
  <!-- RIGHT SPACER CELL // -->

 </tr>

</table>
<tr>
 <!-- // SOCIAL MEDIA -->

     <td class="footer" align="center" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style=" padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 20px; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 400; text-align: center; color: #575F65;">

     <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/0k25a3lkki3pbip/linkedin_e.png?raw=1" width="19" height="18" style="padding-right: 8px" "padding-bottom: 10px"><a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lnq77di7mue1zs/twitter_e.png?raw=1" width="22" height="18" style="padding-right: 8px"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/as39vdrbwtpvvp7/facebook_e.png?raw=1" width="18" height="18" style="padding-right: 7px"></a><a style=" padding-bottom: 20px" href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5clso0ov6qw97g/instagram_e.png?raw=1" width="18" height="18" style="padding-right: 7px"></a><br>

<!-- // FOOTER -->
        © 2020 , Inc<br>
<a class="appleLinksGrey" style="color: #575F65; " href="https://www..com">www.website.com</a>   |   1-8655<br>
e, CA 91361<br>
       </td>
      </tr>

<!-- FULL EMAIL // -->
</body>
</html>
```